# Trigger a method in parent component from child component. Vue, Vuex

Tags: html, animation, vue.js, vuex

I'm looking to trigger a method holding animations in a parent page view, once a button has been clicked within a child component.

I'm just looking to confirm, this would be the simplest/best practise with vue's current version. (v 3.1.1)

Child

```
 methods: {
  something() { this.$emit('event', [x: y]);
 }
```

Parent

```
 <component @event="handler"></component>
```

Parent Script

```
 methods: {
  handler(params) {
     console.log(params);
  }
 }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That is the correct way.

Comment: As @RoyJ mentioned, this is the correct way. You can name your event (other than `event`) and when defining an object, you should use curly brackets `{}`. Other than that it looks fine. See also the official docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event